# $(this).addClass('why-you-no-working'); not working on waypoint?

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I just tried way points today as it looks awesome,

However, I'm having a hard time trying to make things work,

first simple test, works perfectly,

```
$('.parallax').waypoint(function() {
        alert('I work');
});
```

But when i use $(this), it wont work, e.g.

```
$('.parallax').waypoint(function() {
        $(this).addClass('why-you-no-working');
});
```

you can see the sample from here -> http://jsfiddle.net/4D3bH/425/

the second box should have black background color instead of blue,  but for some reason its simple doesn't work,

if I use something like below, it works fine though, its

```
$('.parallax').waypoint(function() {
            $('.parallax').addClass('why-you-no-working');
});
```

Spent almost three hours trying to get it working, but no luck,

Please help :)

Comment: Please open console and fix all errors in your jsfiddle

Comment: for some reason external js is not working in chrome.. lol.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case `this` does not refer to [`DOMElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). You can get reference to [`DOMElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), inside callback, through property `this.element`

```
$('.parallax:nth-of-type(2)').waypoint(function() {        
    $(this.element).addClass('why-you-no-working');
},{offset: '1%'});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4D3bH/428/)

Comment: you sir save hours of my time. Thank you